# How use Lua patten for get all string?

Tags: lua

I want to get all the strings of a script, I tried to use patten, but in some cases it can give errors

If anyone can help me or give me a tip I would be grateful

I try it:

```lua
Teste = [[
A = "&";
B = '"'
C = '"'
print("'".."'"..'"'..'"')
]]
for string in Teste:gmatch('%"(.-)%"') do

print(string) --[[
&
'
C = '
'
'
'..']]
end
```

Comment: You don't get to unilaterally delete your question just because it's resolved for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match quotes. Try the code below. Note how the pattern remembers and match the quote.

```
Teste = [[
A = "one";
B = 'two'
C = 'three'
print("'1".."'2"..'"3'..'"4')
]]

for q,string in Teste:gmatch('([\"\'])(.-)%1') do
   print(string)
end
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, I will try to understand this code I will try to create my version, but thank you very much I don't know much about patten, but now I am more confident that it is possible

Comment: Will this code work correctly if `Teste` variable contains this whole program?